# How to Repeat an xUnit Test Collection multiple times in parallel

Tags: c#, .net, xunit, xunit.net

Is there a way to repeat an xUnit collection multiple times in parallel? I found that xUnit doesn't seem to support this, but I came across this post: https://www.meziantou.net/parallelize-test-cases-execution-in-xunit.htm which shows how to parallelize single test cases / theories.
I'm trying to accomplish this on an Azure DevOps Pipeline build.

I tried to apply the same logic to collections, but only one collection seems to be run when calling the test on an Azure DevOps.
Here is my function for duplicating the collection:

```
private IEnumerable<IXunitTestCase> SetUpTestCaseParallelization(IEnumerable<IXunitTestCase> testCases)
{
    var result = new List<IXunitTestCase>();
    var oldTestMethod = testCases.First().TestMethod;
    var oldTestClass = oldTestMethod.TestClass;
    var oldTestCollection = oldTestMethod.TestClass.TestCollection;
    
    // create testSuiteRuns copies of the collection to run the suite in parallel testSuiteRuns times
    for (int c = 0; c < testSuiteRuns; c++) 
    {
        var newTestCollection =
            new TestCollection(
                oldTestCollection.TestAssembly,
                oldTestCollection.CollectionDefinition,
                displayName: $"{oldTestCollection.DisplayName} {oldTestCollection.UniqueID}");
        newTestCollection.UniqueID = Guid.NewGuid();

        var newTestClass = new TestClass(newTestCollection, oldTestClass.Class);

        // Duplicate each test and assign it to the new collection
        foreach (var testCase in testCases) 
        {
            var testMethod = testCase.TestMethod;
            var newTestMethod = new TestMethod(newTestClass, testMethod.Method);
            switch (testCase)
            {
                // Used by Theory having DisableDiscoveryEnumeration or non-serializable data
                case XunitTheoryTestCase xunitTheoryTestCase:
                    result.Add(new XunitTheoryTestCase(
                        DiagnosticMessageSink,
                        GetTestMethodDisplay(xunitTheoryTestCase),
                        GetTestMethodDisplayOptions(xunitTheoryTestCase),
                        newTestMethod));
                    break;

                // Used by all other tests
                case XunitTestCase xunitTestCase:
                    result.Add(new XunitTestCase(
                        DiagnosticMessageSink,
                        GetTestMethodDisplay(xunitTestCase),
                        GetTestMethodDisplayOptions(xunitTestCase),
                        newTestMethod,
                        xunitTestCase.TestMethodArguments));
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Test case " + testCase.GetType() + " not supported");
            }
        }
    }
    
    return result;

    static TestMethodDisplay GetTestMethodDisplay(TestMethodTestCase testCase)
    {
        return (TestMethodDisplay)typeof(TestMethodTestCase)
            .GetProperty("DefaultMethodDisplay", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)!
            .GetValue(testCase)!;
    }

    static TestMethodDisplayOptions GetTestMethodDisplayOptions(TestMethodTestCase testCase)
    {
        return (TestMethodDisplayOptions)typeof(TestMethodTestCase)
            .GetProperty("DefaultMethodDisplayOptions", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)!
            .GetValue(testCase)!;
    }
}
```

(I should also mention that the collection I'm trying to duplicate has a collection fixture.)

After making the custom framework, which I named `ParallelTestCollectionFramework`, I put it in my collection file to run it with `[assembly: Xunit.TestFramework(typeName: "Xunit.Custom.ParallelTestCollectionFramework", assemblyName: "BasicAssembly")]`. I expect the collection to be run `testSuiteRuns` times but that's not happening.

Comment: By definition, a collection in XUnit runs its tests serially, not in parallel. (See https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel) What you could try, however, is to make another collection or set of collections. Define classes derived from your original test classes (without any methods of their own) and put them in the new collection(s). The original tests will run in the derived classes in parallel to those in the original collection. You will also have to duplicate the collection fixture for the new collections to provide the new collection with the fixture objects they need.

Comment: I see thanks! Do you know if there's a way to do this programmatically instead of defining a duplicate collection multiple times? I can't find any documentation on the collection set.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how or if it can be done programmatically.